# How do I use null within a ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am rendering a page with react and react-bootstrap, with the use of `<ListGroup>` and `<ListGroupItem>`. The following is my code, and I'm trying to use `bsStyle='info'` when the status is not `'1'`, and leave it blank when status is `'1'`.

```
<ListGroup>
  {tables.map(table => (
    <ListGroupItem
      key={`table.${table.id}`}
      header=(table.name)
      bsStyle={table.status !== '1' ? ('info') : ('')}
      >
      {table.content} - 
    </ListGroupItem>
  ))}
</ListGroup>
```

It rendered properly but keeps getting the following warning due to validation of bsStyle:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `bsStyle` of value `` supplied to `ListGroupItem`, expected one of ["success","warning","danger","info"].
```

There is a workaround to escape the validation by setting `bsStyle={null}`. However I can't get it works within the ternary expression. The following code will make it a string `bsStyle='{null}'`.

```
<ListGroup>
  {tables.map(table => (
    <ListGroupItem
      key={`table.${table.id}`}
      header=(table.name)
      bsStyle={table.status !== '1' ? ('info') : ('{null}')}
      >
      {table.content} - 
    </ListGroupItem>
  ))}
</ListGroup>
```

What is the proper way to pass `{null}` without making it a string?

EDITED: Supposed to be '{null}' and not '{null' up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to ommit whole bsStyle attribute in case status is not different from 1

```
<ListGroupItem
   key={`table.${table.id}`}
   header=(table.name)
   {...( table.status !== '1' ? {bsStyle:'info'} : {} )}
  >
```

Comment: Actually i prefer this over passing null somewhere when i really don't want to set a prop at all.

Answer (score 4):

Your ternary operator's second operand is off:

```
('{null}')
```

That evaluates to literally `"{null}"`. Try this:

```
bsStyle={table.status !== '1' ? 'info' : null}
```

Just use `null` plainly, do not wrap it in quotes. Here's [a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6wemmj/4/).

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of surprised that returning `"{null"` bypassed the validation...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Actually, [it does throw an error](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6wemmj/3/) OP just didn't say so.

Comment: it's a typo there, I meant {null}, edited above. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/306

Comment: @YenSheng Edited my answer; but my answer still applies. There's no reason to add so much extra complexity to just not include the property -- the property is completely ignored if it has a `null` value.